# Type infer error on seemingly simple class method

Tags: python, class, methods, numba

During running (numba compilation) of the following class method:

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def isInPosition(self):
    """Returns whether the axis is in the desired position."""
    return True if self.state & 0x04 else False
```

I receive a type infer error message:

cannot determine Numba type of class X.X

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 2):

If you're in `nopython` mode each variable's type must be supported by numba. Non-static-methods in Python take a `self` argument and as long as you're not using a `jitclass` then the type of `self` isn't supported in `nopython` mode which makes it impossible to `jit` it like that.

However you could refactor it in an unjitted method and a jitted function:

```
import numba as nb

@nb.njit
def _is_in_position(state):
    return bool(state & 0x04)

class Fun:
    def __init__(self, state):
        self.state = state

    def is_in_position(self):
        return _is_in_position(self.state)
```

You could also check if it's faster if you `jit` the method in object mode, maybe it can inline the inner function call:

```
import numba as nb

@nb.njit
def _is_in_position(state):
    return bool(state & 0x04)

class Fun:
    def __init__(self, state):
        self.state = state

    @nb.jit
    def is_in_position(self):
        return _is_in_position(self.state)
```

Depending on the class it could be possible to make it a jitclass (but jitclass requires everything to be typed with **supported** types so it's likely that you cannot do that):

```
import numba as nb

spec = [
    ('state', nb.int64),
]

@nb.jitclass(spec)
class Fun(object):
    def __init__(self, state):
        self.state = state

    def is_in_position(self):
        return bool(self.state & 0x04)
```

Comment: Thanks. And how can you "define" other python classes in a "spec"?

Comment: Depends on what "other Python classes" you mean. Note that numba is a very specific optimizer, not a general one. So there's only a small subset of Python which is supported.

Comment: Sorry, I was not concrete enough. I meant my other classes. If one class instance is given as a parameter to the __init__ (or any other method), I suppose I have to "declare" it in the spec or at the method. How do I do it?

Comment: @Lazac Perhaps it would be more understandable if you ask a *new question* and provide an exemplaric use-case. In general you cannot put self-written classes in the spec, except these are `jitclass`es but it really depends on the setup (what does the class store beside other classes) and such like.